# Showing that $\inf \{\|u-g(u)\| : u \in C \} = 0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C \subseteq X$ be closed, convex and bounded. Moreover, let $g:C \to C$ be a non-expansive operator, meaning that :
>   $$\|g(u) - g(v) \| \leq \|u-v\| \; \forall u,v \in C$$
>   Show that : 
>   $$\inf\{\|u-g(u)\|:u \in C\} = 0$$

**Attempt :**

Since $X$ is Banach and $C$ is closed, this means that $C$ is also Banach.

Since it is $g : C \to C$, this means that $g(C) \subseteq C$. Since $C$ is convex, any such $g_n \in g(C)$ can be written as 
$$g_n(x) = (1-r_n)y + r_ng(x)$$
with $x,y \in C$ and $\{r_n\}_{n \geq 1} \in [0,1]$ with $r_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1$.

It also is :

$$\|g_n(x) - g_n(z) \| = r_n \|g(x) - g(z)\| \leq r_n\|x-z\|\; \forall x,z \in C$$

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1} \in C$ such that $g_n(x_n) = x_n$. Then :
$$x_n = (1-r_n)y + r_ng(x_n)$$
But this leads to :
$$\|x_n -g(x_n) \| = (1-r_n)\|y-g(x_n)\|$$
But since $C$ is also bounded, $\|y-g(x_n)\|$ will be a finite number and thus :
$$\|x_n - g(x_n) \| = (1-r_n)\|y-g(x_n)\| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$$
$$\implies$$
$$\inf\{\|u-g(u)\|:u \in C\} = 0$$

**I would really appreciate any feedback on this attempt, since it was completely based on intuitions (I have never handled something similar before). Any hints, tips or alternative elaborations will be most welcome.**

Comment: I don't see a question?

Comment: @Math_QED There is a bold text section at the end ?

Comment: Check the exercice. What are you trying to prove?

Comment: @Math_QED Oh, apologies. The point is to prove $\inf\{\|u-g(u)\|:u \in C\} = 0$ but I probably deleted it by mistake from the exercise's body while typing.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at your attempt now.

Comment: What exactly is $g_n$?

Comment: @Math_QED A contraction mapping I constructed taking advantage of the convexity.

Comment: But you say $g_n \in g(C)$, thus it is an element of $C$ and no map?

Comment: @Math_QED As mentioned, my experience of contractions and non-expansive operators is non-existent. So any theoritical mistakes are possible and this is why I posted this as a question.

Comment: This is known as the almost fixed point property: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-088-01/S0002-9939-1983-0691276-4/S0002-9939-1983-0691276-4.pdf

Comment: The sequence generated by $g_n$ is indeed a sequence of contraction operators, since $\|g_n(x)-g_n(z)\| \leq r_n\|x-z\|$ with $r_n \in [0,1)$ and $r_n \to 1$. (As a comment to the deleted answer and point below).

Comment: Since you asked for feedback: your writing is incomprehensible. I don't know how much of this is a language problem and how much is a maths problem. I suspect both play a part. With just a bit of effort you can probably improve both and edit your question accordingly. This will increase your chances to get feedback